# iPhone 11 no text notification for my fiance

Tags: iphone, messages, notifications

For the past two or three days whenever my fiancé sends me a text, I won’t get a notification or anything. I’ve checked my *Do not Disturb* settings and the Alerts tab on her messages and I can not figure it out.  It is on iOS 13.3 through the iMessage app
I’ve checked do not disturb I’ve checked the alerts tab I’ve turned both phones off and on and I’ve cleared our texts from both phones and nothing is working it only does it with her no one else
Has anyone else had this problem if so, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Try to erase all conversation history with you from her phone (ie, phone 1 text phone 2 but nothing get to phone 2, erase the history conversation on phone 1)

Comment: That didn’t work

Comment: Please [edit] to add your exact iOS version, and a little clarification whether it is iMessage or not. @AustinWilson also it'd be helpful if you go through this site for similar questions and list in your post what you've tried.

Comment: Is this only with the one contact, your fiancé, or is this with other/all contacts as well?

Comment: I entered the iOS on there it is iMessage and yes that’s the only contact it does it with

Comment: Check to see if you created any custom ring/alert tones for her.  You can also try deleting the contact and adding her back in as "new".  Also, be sure to @ the user you're replying to so we get a notification in our inbox.  This way, replies can be more timely!